# Obj-C, how do I release a NSString return value?

Tags: xcode, object, memory-leaks

I'm trying to gain a NSString value from my database in a function, however I keep get analyzer warnings. Heres my code...

```
- (NSString*)getCategoryDesc:(int)pintCid { 
NSString *ret;
ret = value from my db ...  
return [ret autorelease];
}
```

It doesn't like

```
return ret;
return [ret retain];
```

Comment: what warning do you get? and how do you get your 'ret' string? does it comes retained, autoreleased or else?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point (which you're not showing us) is: what does "value from my db" do?

If it's doing something like:

```
ret = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"something"];
```

then you are responsible for releasing the object, but if it's doing something like

```
ret = [NSString stringWithString:@"something"];
```

you do not need to release it (and, indeed, you must NOT).

Because your method is named "get*" (and not "create*"), you need to return an object that the caller does not own (generally, that means an autoreleased object).

Read up on the [object ownership policy rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1).